# node labels from jenkins api

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way I can extract node labels from jenkins API? The [standard](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API):

```
{base_url}/computer/{node}/api
```

did not seem to have any label information. Is it in some other place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, node labels are part of node configuration, so they live in

```
{base_url}/computer/{node_str}/config.xml
```

Here is my hack to access that through python jenkinsapi (similar to job configuration), from `node_str`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

j = Jenkins(...)
n = j.get_node(node_str)
response = n.jenkins.requester.get_and_confirm_status( "%(baseurl)s/config.xml" % n.__dict__)
_element_tree = ET.fromstring(response.text)
node_labels = _element_tree.find('label').text
```

Answer (score 5):

The [ruby client](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client) offers a way to obtain the configuration XML file through a call. That file can then be processed to extract the label information.

```
require "rubygems"
require "jenkins_api_client"

# Initialize the client by passing in the server information
# and credentials to communicate with the server
client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(
  :server_ip => "127.0.0.1",
  :username => "awesomeuser",
  :password => "awesomepassword"
)

# Obtain the XML of the desired node
xml = client.node.get_config("nodename")

# Extract label information
xml =~ /<label>(.*)<\/label)/

# As we can have multiple space-separated labels, we need to split them
labels = []
$1.split(" ").each { |label| labels << label }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using BeautifulSoup and urllib2, you can do this to create a dictionary of label lists keyed by the node names. Admittedly fragile and hackish but works with Jenkins ver. 1.512

```
JENKINS_URL = "http://jenkins.mycompany.com"

from jenkinsapi import jenkins
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

node_labels = dict()
jenkins_obj = jenkins.Jenkins(JENKINS_URL)
node_names = jenkins_obj.get_node_dict().keys()
for node_name in node_names:
    if node_name is not "master":
        req = urlopen('{}/computer/{}/'.format(JENKINS_URL,node_name))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.read())
        node_labels[node_name] = [tag.text for tag in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"tag0 model-link"})]
```

Answer (score 3):

The Python solutions here generally did not seem to work any longer (the `jenkinsapi` I could find on PyPI did not have some of the expected methods) and anyway, it would require authentication tokens I could not easily get a hold of.

https://jenkins.internal/computer/api/json?pretty=true would get me a listing of all the nodes with the `assignedLabel` structure for each. This was enough for me (I just needed an inventory of the labels we use - it would be nice if they had descriptions too, but alas, most don't).

```sh
jq -r '.computer[].assignedLabels[].name' jenkins-labels.json | sort -u
```

gets a listing of the labels as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be OK:
http://{JENKINS_URL}/label/{LABEL_NAME}/api/json?pretty=true

Comment: This does add some extra fields over the XML API, which is interesting. It gets you the OS string, which may be all some people need (I'm looking for which of my nodes are Windows 2012), but doesn't bring back the labels.