# View all labels in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, label

Is there a easy way to get a list of all node labels in Jenkins?

I can see which labels are set on each node (.../computer/) and which nodes have the same label (.../label/). But similar to listing all nodes on .../computer/ there is no listing of all the labels on .../label/

The approach with [python and jenkinsapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531919/node-labels-from-jenkins-api) or similar seem a bit too advanced for a listing that probably already is available in Jenkins (but not visible?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Haven't installed/tried it myself, but [the "label linked jobs" jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Label+Linked+Jobs+Plugin) has a *label dashboard* as one of its features.. it sounds like this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, that did add some overview of the labels. Could have had some filtering function but will do.

Comment: Note that this plugin doesn't work with multi-configuration/matrix projects.

Answer (score 9):

Just came across this question. Since I did not want to install a new plugin I tried to achieve the same using the script console.

You even have to possibility to filter-out labels. The following example will filter-out any node name from the list - which is considered a label, too, but probably not relevant to most users:

```
def allLabels = []

Jenkins.instance.nodes.each { node ->
  node.assignedLabels.each { label ->
    if (label as String != node.name) {
        allLabels += label
    }      
  }
}

println allLabels.unique().join('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the Scriptler plugin with the "show labels overview" script that is available from the remote script catalogue. This draws an ascii art table of all nodes versus all labels and makes it easy to see at a glance all the labels that  are defined and what nodes use them.

Answer (score -1):

Similar like GBEE suggestion (scripts migth be similar):
Using the [script consol](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/) of jenkins (Manage Jenkins > Script Consol) you can use groovy scripts too.

The script [https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/show-labels-overview.groovy](http://Edit:%20https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/show-labels-overview.groovy) creates an ascii table of labels and agents.

Something like this:

```
                                       |b|d|
                                       |a|c|
                                       | |e|
                                       | |f|
                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Agent_1                                | | |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abcd-agent                             |X| |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abcd-agent2                            | |X|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```